# Email Accounts in cPanel

Tags: cpanel

I want to migrate from cPanel to a custom panel.
I started with migrating the email accounts but I can't find the account infos:

- email address
- password hash

Where is this email account info stored in cPanel backup file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can able to get backup of all mails in two ways

**Solution1:**

Follow the below Steps

1.Login into cpanel

2.Go to the home directory

3.Open the Mail folder

4.open a  domain name folder

5.you can able to see list of email-is folder

6.compress the folders and get the backup of mails.

**Solution 2:**

1.Install outlook or Thunderbird or live mail into your pc

2.Get the mail configuration details into your hosting provider and  configure the email-id into your 
PC outlook or thunderbird.

3.Download all mails into your local pc.

It is the simple way to get the backup of your mails into your local pc

Answer (score 0):

I've done several email migrations, including from CPANEL to Office 365. From my experience the best thing to do is one of this two things:

- If your users use Outlook or any other offline application, just create all the emails in the new panel and let the users define their passwords. Help them on configuring the new email account in Outlook, for example, and afterwards they just need to copy all the emails to the new account.
- If your users only use webmail, just let the cpanel accounts active for them to be able to see the emails on their old account. In my opinion, trying to export/import all this information is not the best option. If you want them to have the old emails in the new accounts, just tell them to use the strategy of downloading with Outlook or other software the emails and copy/move them to the new account.

If you were migrating between versions of the same panel, lets say for example from Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2013, it would have been easy to import the information, and maintain the login info, because you were probably using AD.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **imapsync** or **popsync** to migrate emails .
Please create email id on new server and use below command after installing imapsync

**imapsync --host1 server1.example.com --user1 sales@example.com --passfile1 /etc/secret2 --host2 server2.example.com --user2 sales@example.com --passfile2 /etc/secret2**

or not with passfile

**imapsync    --host1 old.mailserver.com --user1 test@domain.com --password1 mypasswd    --host2 new.mailserver.com --user2 test@domain.com --password2 mypasswd**

you need to install imapsync first with the following command **Note** this command is for centos 6
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm**

yum install imapsync

Answer (score 0):

If you just like to migrate the emails then perform the imap sync that is best and easiest way to perform the email migration. Just you will need to make sure that your old and new server have open the imap for the migration.

If it's failing then best option is configure the email account using the old setting in one of your local system. Download all emails in it. That's it.